# have error in postman with POST request to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, postman

Making first steps in elasticsearch and reading article 
https://www.elastic.co/blog/a-practical-introduction-to-elasticsearch
I try to send requests in postman and got error:

"error": "Content-Type header [multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------039246746046020007284747] is not supported",
"status": 406

I filled 2 tabs in postman:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXkOa.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDv5n.jpg

Which options did I miss ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send the body as raw JSON:

[image]

You've chosen `form-data` which is not supported in ES. It's JSON-in, JSON-out.

Comment: still didn't solve it for me